# Bash command “reset” — dash (sh) equivalent?

Tags: android, dash

When the fonts get messed up in dash *(jackpal.androidterm)*, how do I reset that one?

When printing contents of binary files, special characters can mess up the terminal character set. How can this be reset in the dash shell?

Comment: `reset` is not a Bash command and not related to the shell. There are a few versions of a similar command around; the one called `reset` on my system came from ncurses and does the same thing whichever shell you launched it from. I don't know how/if it's possible to install something in your environment.

Answer (score 4):

`reset` is not a bash builtin. It should work the same in `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc. An alternative to it is `tput reset`.

But

a) neither `reset` nor `tput` is present in android, and

b) `jackpal.androidterm` doesn't seem to support any reset escape, like `xterm`, etc.

Maybe I'm wrong about the latter claim -- but the only way I was ever able to reset it was via its "Reset Term" menu command.

Comment: A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/blob/master/emulatorview/src/main/java/jackpal/androidterm/emulatorview/TerminalEmulator.java) agrees with that.  It implements about 15% of xterm, and is missing the various "reset" features...